# Add an action button to WooCommerce "my account" orders according to product id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I have a WooCommerce b2b shop, where I sell different types of products. For example, e-learning courses accessible by code redemption. I also sell books.

What I tried was to create a customer action in the "my orders" section which allows to send lists of participant data for my e-learning courses.

And I want this action only to be shown for course products, not books. I tried this, **but the action still shows as well for the book product**

```php
function add_my_account_order_actions( $actions, $order ) {
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    if ( array( $item[ 'variation_id' ] ) &&  $item[ 'variation_id' ] == (3558 or 3559 or 3560 or 3561 or 3557));  {
    $actions['tn'] = array(
        // adjust URL as needed
        'url'  => '/teilnehmer/?&order=' . $order->get_order_number(),
        'name' => __( 'Teilnehmerdaten', 'my-textdomain' ),
    );
    }
    return $actions;
    }
}
    
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'add_my_account_order_actions', 10, 2 );
```

---

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use `return $actions` outside the foreach loop,
  because if some condition is not met in your code, the return will never be reached
- to compare multiple product id's from the order with a predefined array, you can use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```php
function add_my_account_order_actions( $actions, $order ) {
    
    // Set Id's
    $product_ids = array ( 3558, 3559, 3560, 3561, 3557 );
    
    // Loop through order
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    
        // Product Id is in the array
        if ( in_array( $item['product_id'], $product_ids ) ) {
            $actions['tn'] = array(
                // adjust URL as needed
                'url'  => '/teilnehmer/?&order=' . $order->get_order_number(),
                'name' => __( 'Teilnehmerdaten', 'my-textdomain' ),
            );
        }
    }

    // Return
    return $actions;
}
    
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'add_my_account_order_actions', 10, 2 );
```